# mod_rewrite to mask url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using WP, & I want to use a `mod_rewrite` rule such that all images from `wp-content/uploads` folder shows a different URL.

eg:

`www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpeg` --->
`www.example.com/media/image.jpeg`

I've placed a rule in `.htaccess` but it returns a 404 error.

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ /media/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

[Here's the `.htaccess` code.](http://pastebin.com/JDVtaeTV)

Comment: By default, WordPress may create its own `.htaccess`. Will the other rules affecting your rule?

Comment: the default rules created by wp are in place I've just appended my rule on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this (all of these rules need to be before the default wordpress rules):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+wp-content/uploads/([^\?\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /media/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/media/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/uploads/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^media/(.+)$ /wp-content/uploads/$1 [L]
```

Comment: exactly.. something like it... I don't get a 404 when clicked on the image, but when hovered on the image it shows the original location as `/wp-content/uploads/` can I tweak it to show the redirected URL as well on mouse hover?

Comment: @SimonKB mod_rewrite can **not** change the content of your pages. Those links are anchors, and mod_rewrite can only change them *once they are requested*, not the content of the pages themselves. You'll have to look into proxies for doing that, or change the content so they point to the /media links instead.